# Updating multiple records using jQuery and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Please, I need assistance on how to use jQuery to submit multiple records for update using php. Below is the html code:

```
string += "<tbody><tr class='rowca'><td>#</td><td>" +value.sID+ 
"</td><td>" +value['Full Names']+ "</td><td><input type='text' name='ca1[]' 
id='ca1' class='entry' maxlength='2' value='" +value.ca1+ "'></td><td><input 
type='text' name='ca2[]' id='ca2' class='entry' maxlength='2' value='" 
+value.ca2+ "'></td><td><input type='text' name='ca3[]' id='ca3' 
class='entry' maxlength='2' value='" +value.ca3+ "'></td><td><input 
type='text' name='ca4[]' id='ca4' class='entry' maxlength='2' value='" 
+value.exam+ "'></td><td><input type='text' name='ca5[]' id='ca5' 
class='total' readonly value='" +value.total+ "'></td><td><input type='text' 
name='ca6[]' id='ca6' class='demo' readonly value='" +value.grade+ "'></td>
<td><input type='text' name='ca7[]' id='ca7' class='remark' readonly 
value='" +value.remarks+ "'></td></tr><input type='text' name='sid[]' 
id='sid' value='" +value.sID+ "'>";
});
string += "</tbody></table>";
string += "<p><input type='button' value='Save CAs' id='savecas'></p>";
```

Using the below code only gets the first row of student record updated instead of the multiple records:

```
$(function(){
$('#savecas').on('click',function(){
    var url = 'update_student_cas_ajax.php';
    var ca_1 = $('#ca1').val();
    var ca_2 = $('#ca2').val();
    var ca_3 = $('#ca3').val();
    var ca_4 = $('#ca4').val();
    var ca_5 = $('#ca5').val();
    var ca_6 = $('#ca6').val();
    var ca_7 = $('#ca7').val();
    var sids = $('#sid').val();
    var sess = $('#session').val();
    var trm = $('#term').val();
    var subj = $('#subject').val();
    var cid = $('#staffclass').val();        

 if(confirm('Are You Sure You want to submit all CAs'))
 {
 if(!sess || !trm || !subj || !sids || !ca_1 || !ca_2 || !ca_3 || !ca_4 || !ca_5 || !ca_6 || !ca_7 || !cid)
 {
 $('.error').show(100).html('All Fields Are Required. Thanks').delay(500).fadeOut(2000);
 }else{
 $.post(url, {term:trm, subj:subj, sid:sids, ca1:ca_1, ca2:ca_2, ca3:ca_3,
ca4:ca_4, ca5:ca_5, ca6:ca_6, ca7:ca_7, sess:sess, cid:cid}).done(function(data){
 if(data>0){
 $('.success').show(100).html('CAs Saved Successfully').delay(1000).fadeOut(2000);}else{
 $('.error').show(100).html('Unable to save Students CAs').delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
      }
    });
   }
  }
 });
});
```

I just added my php code named update_student_cas_ajax.php

```
$session = trim($_POST['sess']);
$cID = trim($_POST['cid']);
$subID = trim($_POST['subj']);
$term = trim($_POST['term']);
$ca1 = trim($_POST['ca1']);
$ca2 = trim($_POST['ca2']);
$ca3 = trim($_POST['ca3']);
$exam = trim($_POST['ca4']);
$total = trim($_POST['ca5']);
$grade = trim($_POST['ca6']);
$remark = trim($_POST['ca7']);
$sID = trim($_POST['sid']);

$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE terminal_assessment SET ca1=:ca_1, ca2=:ca_2, 
ca3=:ca_3, exam=:ca_4, total=:ca_5, grade=:ca_6, remarks=:ca_7 WHERE 
term=:trm AND session=:sess AND classID=:class_ID AND subID=:sub_ID AND 
sID=:stID");

$data = $stmt->execute(array(":ca_1"=>$ca1, ":ca_2"=>$ca2, ":ca_3"=>$ca3, 
":ca_4"=>$exam, "ca_5"=>$total, ":ca_6"=>$grade, ":ca_7"=>$remark, 
":class_ID"=>$cID, ":trm"=>$term, ":sub_ID"=>$subID, ":sess"=>$session, 
":stID"=>$sID));

if($data)
{
    $result = 1;
}

echo $result;
$db = null;
?>
```

Comment: There is no PHP here.

Comment: sorry i didn't include the php code. do i include it as well

Comment: Use a form and `serialize()` to get all data for the form

Comment: @charlietfl pls i can't really get that done just as u've said. i can only make it work using html form post and php. but i want to use jquery to do that instead.

Comment: You use a form and [jQuery serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to create all the data to pass to php through ajax

Comment: @JayBlanchard i have added the php code. thanks

Comment: "only gets the first row of student record". According to your HTML there's only one row anyway. However if there _were_ multiple rows your HTML would be invalid, because `id` must be unique for each element on the page. And `.val()` only ever gets the value of the first element it matches (even if it could actually match multiple elements with identical IDs, which it can't). You can read that in the jQuery documentation for `.val()` on the very first line: http://api.jquery.com/val/.

Comment: It also looks like your PHP is only set up to handle one row of data too. The only thing you've got that relates to multiple rows is the `[]`s at the end of your "name" attributes. The rest of it does not support what you state you're trying to do.

Comment: But anyway, when submitting via ajax, instead of tediously fetching each field separately, just use http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ against the form element to fetch all the form values into one querystring. e.g. `$.post(url, $(this).closest("form").serialize()).done(//...etc`.

Comment: @ADyson ok. i will have to do some modifications then base upon ur advice. Thanks for the help.